# FFmpeg concat of mov files via pipe input fails on versions newer than 4.2.3

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

I've been using ffmpeg 4.2.3 to concat h264 mov files from a DSLR camera using the following:

```
ls input1.MOV input2.MOV | perl -ne 'print "file $_"' | ffmpeg -f concat -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -safe 0 -i - -c copy output.MOV
```

After updating to version ffmpeg 4.4, running the same command returns the following error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fd283004400] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fd283004400] moov atom not found
[concat @ 0x7fd283803000] Impossible to open 'pipe:input1.MOV'
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

With either version, specifying mov files in concat.txt and running the following works fine:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -c copy output.MOV
```

I've rolled back to ffmpeg 4.2.3 to continue using the pipe input. What changed between versions that is causing the pipe input to fail, and is there a better way to write the command to work with the current version?

Comment: Version 4.3.1 also works correctly, but the newest version 5.0 does not. Still seeking a better way to write the command to work with the current version of ffmpeg.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1368547 this works for me (formatting the stdin stream as `file file:path`)

Comment: Even after a lot of searching I did not find this question, looks like mine at https://superuser.com/questions/1712123/ffmpeg-moov-atom-not-found-on-a-seemingly-valid-file is about the same problem.