# ffmpeg: "moov atom not found" on a seemingly valid file

Tags: ffmpeg, video

GoPro cameras cut up video in 4GB MP4 files.

Attempting to merge them with ffmpeg 4.4.1 like so:

```
ls GH017642.MP4 GH027642.MP4 | while read line; do echo "file '$line'"; done | ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -i - -c copy out.mp4
```

fails with:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5573df8c9ec0] moov atom not found
[concat @ 0x5573df8b7ec0] Impossible to open 'pipe:GH017642.MP4'
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

"moov" does seem to be present in that file, though:

```
> ffmpeg -v trace -i GH017642.MP4 2>&1 | grep -e type:\'mdat\' -e type:\'moov\'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55a71e111dc0] type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 3999992669 28 4001343671
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55a71e111dc0] type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 1350982 3999992697 4001343671
```

Additionally, both Quicktime and VLC play that file just fine.

What could cause the ffmpeg error, how to fix it?

Comment: You might want to check if the error persists if you specify the input file normally instead of piping it.

Comment: Wow, great call - that did help. Any guess why that could happen, if the piping method has been reported elsewhere as working properly?

Comment: Hard to say, you might want to include to your question how exactly you are trying to pipe the data.

Comment: After seing that you use `-f concat`: Are you trying to pipe a list of tiles to `ffmpeg` ?

Comment: In most cases it is not possible to pass MP4 as input to a pipe, because the "moov atom" is usually at the end of the MP4 file, and the pipe is "non-seekable" (and FFmpeg looks for the "moov atom" before reading the video and audio streams). You may move the "moov atom" to the beginning of the file (using FFmpeg), or use other type of file container.

Comment: I had excluded the piping of the file list for brevity, added in the question now. Only the file listing is piped, actual video files are not (thus "moov atom" should be easy to seek to).